# Android User permission - Modify Phone State giving Error

Tags: android

I wanted to try a [tutorial for blocking calls](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.com/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html) for 2.2 on emulator. But `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` gives me an error, saying that this is a system permission error in android `manifest file`.

Do I need modify phone state permission to block calls? If so, I am not sure how to remove system permission error.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: please update your logcat error

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse,

goto `Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking.`

There in `CorrectNess` section you will see `ProtectedPermission` in `Id` column, select it.
At the bottom of the window you will see its `Severity` to be `Error`(It is default value.) Change it to anything less sever than Error.

Hope it helps you.